# Find exact value of $\sin\left(\dfrac x2\right) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have tried this problem over and over but can not get it. Can anyone provide a solution?

Given $\sin(x) = -\dfrac67$  and $\tan(x)\gt0$ , find the exact value of $\sin\left(\dfrac x2\right) $.

Comment: Choose the correct quadrant as in lab bhattacharjee's answer then you can follow $$\sin x=\dfrac{2\tan (x/2)}{1+\tan^2(x/2)}=-\dfrac{6}{7}$$ $$3\tan^2(x/2)+7\tan(x/2)+3=0$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sin x=-\frac67<0,\tan x>0$$

$\implies x$ lies in the third Quadrant $\implies \pi<x<\dfrac{3\pi}2\implies\cos x<0$
$\implies\cos x=-\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$

and $\dfrac\pi2<\dfrac x2<\dfrac{3\pi}4\implies\sin\dfrac x2>0$

As $\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y, \sin\dfrac x2=+\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos x}2}$